# running grails locally with no external network connectivity

Tags: grails-2.0

I was trying to run grails on a computer with no internet connectivity but was not able to do so.  The error I observed is copied below.

```
Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies - Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1
Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found.  This is normally due to internet connectivity issues or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.  Please verify your configuration to continue.
```

I could not locate any config settings that I could change in BuildConfig.groovy or any other groovy file that would allow me to run a grails app (on Windows) with no internet connectivity.  I am sure there must be some settings which allow me to run a grails app without internet connectivity - can anyone possibly shed some light on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Internet connectivity to run grails app locally.
But you need to have your app dependencies downloaded in local Ivy cache - so you need Internet connectivity at least for the first run/compile of your app.
After that you should be able to run it without Internet connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

Though Grails does not require internet conncetivity to run, the Grails software relies on other code which is hosted online. You will need to either download all of the dependencies, (I'm not sure where you would even find them all), or connect to the internet for your initial run.

Once you are online, type `grails run-app` in the console, let that download all the dependencies, then feel free to take it offline!